# GaxiosError: invalid_grant in my nodejs app while i'm sending mail with nodemailer package using google api

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, nodemailer

I want to verify user email when user register in my nodejs backend app i'm using the auth2.0 i'm providing the client id, secret but response giving me error

> (GaxiosError: invalid_grant
> at Gaxios._request (/home/amir/Desktop/Nodejs/Auth/backend/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:84:23)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async OAuth2Client.refreshTokenNoCache (/home/amir/Desktop/Nodejs/Auth/backend/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:172:21)
> at async OAuth2Client.refreshAccessTokenAsync (/home/amir/Desktop/Nodejs/Auth/backend/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:196:19)
> at async OAuth2Client.getAccessTokenAsync (/home/amir/Desktop/Nodejs/Auth/backend/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:216:23) )

I'm giving the refresh_token also but its not working i don't know where i'm doing wrong Please anyone can resolve it

This is my code or api's to register user

```
exports.registerHandle = (req, res) => {
const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
let errors = [];

//------------ Checking required fields ------------//
if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
}

//------------ Checking password mismatch ------------//
if (password != password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
}

//------------ Checking password length ------------//
if (password.length < 8) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 8 characters' });
}

if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('register', {
        errors,
        name,
        email,
        password,
        password2
    });
} else {
    //------------ Validation passed ------------//
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
        if (user) {
            //------------ User already exists ------------//
            errors.push({ msg: 'Email ID already registered' });
            res.render('register', {
                errors,
                name,
                email,
                password,
                password2
            });
        } else {

            const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
                "My ID", // ClientID
                "MY Secret", // Client Secret
                "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" // Redirect URL
            );

            oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                refresh_token: "1%2F%2F04T_nqlj9UVrVCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrGm-NOdEKBOakzMn1cbbCHgg2ivkad3Q_hMyBkSQen0b5ABfR8kPR18aOoqhRrSlPm9w"
            });
            const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken()
            console.log('Google Access Token ===', accessToken);

            const token = jwt.sign({ name, email, password }, JWT_KEY, { expiresIn: '30m' });
            console.log('Token ', token);
            const CLIENT_URL = 'http://' + req.headers.host;

            const output = `
            <h2>Please click on below link to activate your account</h2>
            <p>${CLIENT_URL}/auth/activate/${token}</p>
            <p><b>NOTE: </b> The above activation link expires in 30 minutes.</p>
            `;

            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    type: "OAuth2",
                    user: "mygmail@gmail.com",
                    clientId: "My ID",
                    clientSecret: "My Secret",
                    refreshToken: "1%2F%2F04T_nqlj9UVrVCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrGm-NOdEKBOakzMn1cbbCHgg2ivkad3Q_hMyBkSQen0b5ABfR8kPR18aOoqhRrSlPm9w",
                    accessToken: accessToken
                },
            });

            // send mail with defined transport object
            const mailOptions = {
                from: '"Auth Admin" <mygmail@gmail.com>', // sender address
                to: email, // list of receivers
                subject: "Account Verification: NodeJS Auth ✔", // Subject line
                generateTextFromHTML: true,
                html: output, // html body
            };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    req.flash(
                        'error_msg',
                        'Something went wrong on our end. Please register again.'
                    );
                    res.redirect('/auth/login');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Mail sent : %s', info.response);
                    req.flash(
                        'success_msg',
                        'Activation link sent to email ID. Please activate to log in.'
                    );
                    res.redirect('/auth/login');
                }
            })

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid_grant can have a lot of causes. The most common cause is the refresh token expiring.  Apps that are in testing have their consent revoked after seven days this causes the refresh tokens to expire.

You appear to be loading the current access token from the authorization request

```
const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken()
```

Yet you also appear to have a hard coded refresh token

```
refreshToken: "1%2F%2F04T_nqlj9UVrVCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrGm-NOdEKBOakzMn1cbbCHgg2ivkad3Q_hMyBkSQen0b5ABfR8kPR18aOoqhRrSlPm9w",
```

Why not store the latest refresh token instead?

Comment: how i can store latest token please can you describe this

Comment: When you authorize the user the oauth server will return a refresh token to you.   store it where ever you like.

Comment: please can you provide code  or can you edit answer and write code to get new refresh token

Comment: How to get a refresh token with NodeMailer is a separate question.  As its not related to this question. Your question is related to what invalid_grant is and How to fix it. 
 The anwser to that is its because you are using an expired refresh token, and you need to get a new one.  I think you should check the documentation for node mailer https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/  If you cant get it to work open a new question